# validaterequest problem with asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a form that a user fills out and can input html or other text into a textarea.  I have the validaterequest attribute set to false on the page.  However, when I submit the form with any html characters it bombs saying that it detected the potentially dangerous request field and to make validaterequest=false.  I've already done this so I'm not sure why it's not working.  I've done this many times before and never had this problem.  Anyone run into this before and if so, is there a fix?  I don't want to update my web.config and apply it site wide.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147) if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 make sure you add the following to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```